# VHDL Assignment Statement

Tags: vhdl

In my [ASIC book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Application-Specific-Integrated-Circuits-VLSI-Systems/dp/0321602757/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392206448&sr=8-1&keywords=application+specific+integrated+circuits) they are developing a state machine, and they have a statement like:

```
 Shift <= '1' when State = S else '0';
```

However in my project I have multiple states that have the same output being required to turn on so is it possible to write VHDL like this:

```
 Shift <= '1' when State = S OR State = E OR STATE = Q else '0';
```

Or do I have to assign Shift for each of my states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is doable

```
Shift <= '1' when ((State = S) OR (State = E) OR (STATE = Q))
             else '0';
```

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary; the code in the question was already correct.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think it's a good habit to parenthesize conditions in any "programming" language, it makes things much clearer.

Comment: @alexan_e: although some take the view that excessive parens are *less* clear...  I would certainly remove the outer parens